# Javascript: Executing SQL query with dynamic column name

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I have 4 resources, and these resources can be reduced, but every time it's reduced, my function checks if the resource value drops below 0. If it does, then it calls my setColumnToZero function which sets the column value to 0. My problem is that my function won't work when I try to dynamically update the column (1 function for 4 resources.) If I manually Update the column name my code works, but how can I get this to work dynamically

edit: So if I manually type Crop_Inventory instead of ? in my query, it works

```
removeCropFromInventory: function(cropAmount){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let sql = "UPDATE resources SET Crop_Inventory = Crop_Inventory - (?) WHERE resources_FK_PlayerId = (?) AND resources_FK_GameId = (?)";
        var value = [cropAmount, global.id, global.gameId];
        db.query(sql, value, function(err,result,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else{
                crop_inventory = crop_inventory - cropAmount;
                if(crop_inventory < 0){
                    module.exports.setColumnToZero('Crop_Inventory').then(function(crop_inventory){
                        resolve(crop_inventory);
                    });
                } else{
                    resolve(crop_inventory);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}


setColumnToZero: function(Column){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        let sql = "UPDATE resources SET (?) = 0 WHERE resources_FK_PlayerId = (?) AND resources_FK_GameId = (?)"; //This is where error occurs
        var value = [Column, global.id, global.gameId];
        db.query(sql, value, function(err,result,fields){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else{
                crop_inventory = 0
                resolve(crop_inventory);
            }
        });
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Column names, or any identifiers, cannot be parameters; parameters are for values.

Comment: So is there any workaround

Comment: Building your query string in code.

Comment: Ok, so I fixed it by simply doing an if statement for each resource and manually enerering the column name